# C: Why the parens around the pointer?

Tags: c

I'm learning C trough [this tutorial](https://cstack.github.io/db_tutorial/), where I stumbled upon this code:

```
int args_assigned = 
    sscanf(input_buffer->buffer, "insert %d %s %s", 
        &(statement->row_to_insert.id),
        statement->row_to_insert.username, 
        statement->row_to_insert.email);
```

The part that confuses me is `&(statement->row_to_insert.id)`:

I understand it's creating a pointer to the id (in this case a `unit32`), but why is it surrounded by parens? What are them for?

I apologize for the trivial question but I wasn't able to find some documentation on this specific syntax, as I don't know how to call it.

Comment: Parenthesis are used to force expression evaluation. First, the expression inside the parenthesis are evaluated; then, its address is taken.

Comment: If you take a look at the C precedence table you will see that struct operators `->` and `.` have higher precedence than `&`, so in this case the parentheses are not necessary.

Comment: They specify [operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence). Not that it's really needed in this case as `->` has higher precedence than parenthesis.

Comment: They are useless, since `.` and `->` have higher precedence than the `&`

Comment: I disagree they are useless. If one doesn't have the operator precedence table burned into the inside of their skull (I confess to not memorizing it myself), then a single pair of parentheses allows them to understand an expression at a glance.

Comment: @ StoryTeller Nobody said they are useless, we just said they can be omitted, as it is very very very important to understand code that has been written by some maniac that has actually memorized the whole precedence table. I agree on your point being explicit is always better.

Comment: @малинчекуров - *"nobody said they are useless"* --> [*"They are useless"*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50345045/c-why-the-parens-around-the-pointer#comment87705884_50345045).

Comment: @StoryTeller Oh come on ;) ok my bad

Comment: I add extra parentheses to my own example code for readability, and find them useful even after a couple of decades of programming in C: less cognitive load, letting me dedicate all of my feeble brain power into the complex underlying structure or ebb-and-flow instead. (I am still working on writing better comments, though: describing the intent, not the action, of the code.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is probably just for readibility. `&(statement->row_to_insert.id)` is equivalent to `&statement->row_to_insert.id` due to operator precedence in C operators `->` and `.` have higher precedence than `&`. You can read more [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence).

Comment: It is for readability, but if the parenthesis gives better or worse readability is debatable.

Comment: What I meant is that in tutorial, when student doesn't know precedence of operators, parenthesis make it more obvious. When one already know the precedence, parentheses doesn't increase readability.

Comment: In this case it only made the student confused, so... probably not the best idea.

Answer (score 0):

I want to add to smbear`s answer and say that while being on the point of operators precedence, we can not omit the operators' associativity.

As you can see the parentheses are placed around `statement->row_to_insert.id`, this is because struct operators `->` and `.` have the same precedence, but associativity `Left-To-Right`.

What that means is `statement->row_to_insert.id` is evaluated in the following order - take `row_to_insert` member of `statement` and then take the `id` member of `row_to_insert`.